# Sum all combinations in vector

Tags: c++

I am trying to calculate the sum of all possible combinations numbers in a vector.  If the combination equals a given number, the function returns false.  If no combination equals that number, the array prints the number and returns true.

This is what I have:

```
bool t(vector<int>vi, int num){
  for(int i = 0; i < vi.size(); i++) {
    int sum=vi[i];
    for(int j = i+1; j < d.size(); j++) {
      if(sum + vi[j] == num) return false;
    }
  }
  cout<< num << endl;
  return true;
}
```

As you can see, I am able to calculate one level of the sums of the numbers given the root point, but I am getting stuck where I have to continue branching higher up.  It seems if should involve the method calling itself and recursively getting farther up the branches, but I am cannot figure out how to do that.

Comment: I found several solutions on SO that involved defining types, but I am sure it can be done with existing types.

Comment: is your sum and x variable are same?

Comment: And what do mean by sum of all possible combination? Combination of how many numbers?

Comment: @ShashwatKumar Yes, I missed that when I was changing variable names.

Comment: Do you mean sums of 2 numbers, then 3, etc?

Comment: @ShashwatKumar The sum of any combination of numbers in a vector, regardless of the size of the vector.  I know it will take a long time for large vectors, but that doesn't matter.

Comment: @Clark Yes.  The sum of all the different combinations, regardless of position in the vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursion is an excellent way to solve this problem.

```
bool t_helper(vector<int>::const_iterator it, vector<int>::const_iterator end, int sum_left)
{
    if (sum_left == 0) return false;
    if (it == end) return true;
    return t_helper(it+1, end, sum_left - *it) && t_helper(it+1, end, sum_left);
}

bool t(const vector<int>& vi, int num)
{
    bool result = t_helper(vi.begin(), vi.end(), num);
    if (result) cout << num << endl;
    return result;
}
```

If you know something extra you may be able to early-exit.  For example, if elements of `vi` are non-negative, then if `sum_left` becomes negative, you can skip the rest of that branch.  Such "pruning" techniques often make an approach like this faster than exhaustive iteration.

Another suggestion for pruning is to return a different value when inclusion of all positive elements on a branch (and only the positive elements) fell short of the target.  That implies that no subset can reach the target either.

Comment: My current purposes will never have a negative number in the array, but I may use that later.

Comment: By the way, how do you get `sum_left` in `t()` without ever declaring it?

Comment: @user2509848: Typo.  The initial case is `sum_left = num`.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematically, you can do this iteratively by imagining the array as a binary string of length `n`. At each index it is either `1` or `0`. If it is `1`, then we add it in the sum, and if it is `0`, we exclude it from the sum.

All you have to do is go through each possible length `n` binary string from `000....000` to `111....111` and sum depending on which indices are activated.

In terms of going through all possible binary strings, you could have an array of size `n` that starts with all indices set to `0`. Then you would just loop till it becomes an array with all indices set to `1`. Each iteration of the loop you would add `1` to the bit at index `n - 1`. If that bit is `1`, set it to `0` and carry over and add `1` to the bit at position `n - 2`, and so on (doing binary addition).

Comment: And if `n < 32`, you may use directly `uint32_t`.